# Center an element with a right-float element with it

Tags: html, css

My problem is as simple as stupid. I have a `<div>` that holds 2 `<p>` on it, where the 2nd `<p>` has a `float: right;` value on it.

How can I center align the first `<p>` with the 2nd `<p>` on it side-by-side?

How it Looks Like now:
[image: How it Looks Like now]

```css
.bubble_text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vw 3vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="bubble_text">Center me Please</p>
  <p style="float: right;">&#10006;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `text-align:center` to the container element and you're good to go

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
  }
.bubble_text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1vw 3vw;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20vw;
    text-align: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <p class = "bubble_text">Center me Please</p>
    <p style = "float: right;">&#10006;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class = "container">
  <p class = "bubble_text">Center me Please</p>
  <p style = "float: right;">&#10006;</p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
container{
  text-align:center;
 }
.bubble_text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vw 3vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20vw;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/jr9s7ayf/